# Thoughts on taking a RESTful GET JSON output and redirecting it into a POST JSON input

Tags: json, rest, redirect, post, get

Lately I've been going hard with Python and Flask to expose a RESTful API for our end users.  At this time, it's only GET methods, no POSTing... until now.

One interesting request that was made to me was to figure out if it was possible to take a GET request, which outputs to JSON and redirects it back into another web service as a POST request.

Think of it like copying data through a web service, if that makes any sense.  Or maybe like "GET-redirect data-POST".

To further drive the point home, I have a simple GET request:

```
urllib2.Request("http://localhost:5000/request/security/773/20110101")
```

The output is JSON and I want to take that data and POST it back to:

```
http://localhost:5000/submit/transaction/773/20110101
```

Assuming data mapping is one to one (which it is).  Is there a way to do that as one call on the server side?  Is that even a smart thing to do?  Just looking for thoughts, ideas and comments.

Comment: I'm far from a web service guru (hence the comment), but one of the books I'm reading suggested that to make a proper RESTful application the HTTP Verb used needs to match its intended purpose.  While this doesn't answer your question I would be inquiring about the "why" in this situation. As mentioned at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/ under the *Use HTTP methods explicitly* section.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Jared.  I too am far from a WS guru but from what I've been reading, The O'Reilly "RESTful Web Services Cookbook" depicts a chapter in performing transactions.  What I was hoping to inquire about is, perhaps, extending that concept and taking the output of a GET request and having those become my transactions.  If you have the book, it's page 213.

Comment: @mastashaka57 I don't have the book.  I think the issue that I would be worried about is that if you are forwarding a GET to a POST.  You still have a GET request at the heart of the request.  If this request is going to modify data I'd be very leery of doing a GET request since those can be saved/cached/etc.

Comment: No, I follow the HTTP verbs to a T.  GET requests is just that, a READ request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems simple enough.  Why not just do the post from your request/security handler?

```
def request_security_handler():
    ....
    data = "Data"
    urllib2.Request("/submit/transaction/773/20110101", data)
    return data
```

If the posting is an optional thing, you could have done a get like:

```
urllib2.Request("http://localhost:5000/request/security/773/20110101?RepostResultTo=/submit/transaction/773/20110101")
```

And then:

```
def request_security_handler(RepostResultTo):
    ....
    data = "Data"
    urllib2.Request(RepostResultTo, data)
    return data
```

In any case for this to be a single round-trip with the server, the server is going to have to do the POST to itself.  The client won't be able to get the results from the GET and then do a POST with 2 round-trips.

Comment: Thanks for your verbose response.  POST is, indeed, an optional task.

Comment: Question: I really like the concept of an optional POST. Can I, perhaps, use a custom URI for this kind of processing?  Perhaps I can use 'http://localhost:5000/submit/transfer/{account from}/{account to}/{date from}/{date to}?  In the server side, it would be routing the appropriate GET message to /request/security and the appropriate POST messages to /submit/transaction.  The input variables would cover both my requests.  Perhaps you can show some more verbose example?

Comment: Yikes, that really goes against GET requests not having any side effects (beyond logging and visitor counting). @mastashake57 if you really want it to go in one request, do it the other way round: POST to the receiving server with the information on how to get the information to post in the entity body of that POST request.

Comment: Of course you do it that way, it seems like you have all the info you need.  Marjan is correct, though, to be RESTful, you should be doing the POST and then returning the info you want instead of doing a POST from a GET.  Technically it doesn't matter, but from a pie-in-the-sky perspective it is better to start with the POST.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, ers81239.  With your input, I think I have a good idea of what to work with.  Thanks!